# Compile one specific Sass-file to a different folder than the rest

Tags: netbeans, sass

I'm creating a Wordpress-theme using HTML, PHP and SASS. The SASS-files compiles to a folder called **'css'**, but since I'm creating a Wordpress theme WP demands that the **style.css** file is located in the same folder as the other theme files.

This is my folder structure:

[image]

Now what I want is to change the compile-settings so that the **style.css** file gets located in the **teamtour-folder** and not the css-folder without manually moving it from the **css-folder** everytime I save, whereas the other scss-files stays in the **css-folder**. The easiest thing to do is just compile every sass-file to the **teamtour-folder**, I know, and this question can only be trivial, but I still want to have an organized folder structure.

I use NetBeans as IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not doable by the default Less/Scss support in NetBeans, the mapping is folder based (although I believe there is some bug/enhancement reported for file based mapping - I'll look into it).

What I would do as the easiest and quickest solution would be to:

- change the mapping for Less compiler to generate css files in teamtour
- have Grunt/Gulp "build (distribution) task" which would move the wanted CSS files to CSS folder

This way you can have a bit "mess" during development, but before publishing your theme, you would execute the build task and let Grunt/Gulp to clean up your structure. You can even map Grunt or Gulp task to "Build" action in NetBeans so at the end you'd only have to right click on your project and select Build.

One note: Gulp is available only in Dev builds of NetBeans

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of it not being possible in Netbeans.. I ended up changing the other files to partials and just import them to the style.scss file and compiling the file to the teamtour-folder. Will check out Gulp or Grunt though :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to let **SASS** compile all its outputs into the **css** directory, and reduce the main theme **CSS** file to a single `@import` statement.  The downside of course is the additional HTTP request.

Another suggestion, which would reduce the number of HTTP requests, would be to have **SASS** compile into the theme root and `@import` all the other **CSS** files into the theme's main **SCSS** file. Then your theme only needs to load a single **CSS** file.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress demands *a* `style.css` in the themes "root" folder - it does not demand that this file is actually loaded when the theme is used. The file is only required to contain the theme name and a few other details in a comment - I suppose this setup is for legacy reasons.

I haven't used `style.css` for actual styles for several years, this is my "boilerplate" `style.css`, and it doesn't look much different when finished.

```
/*
Theme Name: BLANK THEME
Author: Mikk3lRo
Author URI: 
Description: Blank theme
Version: 0.1
License: 
Text Domain: prfx
*/
```

The actual stylesheet is included from a subfolder:

```
wp_enqueue_style('prfx_styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/production.css');
```